# How to use Zend Auth to make values globally available in each action & layout.phtml

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-auth, service-locator

I have implemented Zend Auth by creating a `getServiceConfig()`-like `AuthenticationService` Object in `Module.php`:

```
'AuthService' => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $dbTableAuthAdapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter, 'tblUSRUsers', 'Email', 'Password', "MD5(?)");

                    $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                    $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
                    $authService->setStorage($sm->get('Application\Model\MyAuthStorage'));

                    return $authService;
                },
```

In the controller action, I am getting this object by

```
$this->getServiceLocator()
                    ->get('AuthService');
```

For authentication I obtain the values using

```
$authservice    = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService');
$arrUserDetails = $authservice->getIdentity();
```

Its working fine, these values are available.

But the problem is that `ServiceLocator` is not available in the Controller constructor so can't write the above code there. Writing this code in each and every action doesn't seem to be a good practice. 
Could anyone help out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution would be to have a route event handler, where you set user credentials:

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()
            ->getEventManager ();

        $eventManager->attach (
            MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE,
            function  (MvcEvent $e)
            {
                $auth = $e->getApplication()
                          ->getServiceManager()
                          ->get('AuthService');

                $e->setParam('userinfo', $auth->getUserInfo());
                // update 
                $layout = $e->getViewModel();
                $layout->userinfo = $auth->getUserInfo();           
       });
    }
```

and then access then in the controller like this:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction ()
    {
        $this->getEvent()->getParam('userinfo');
```

Comment: Suppose i have to pass Logged in user's name to layout.phtml. I want to set this information through constructor for Layout. But,
$this->getEvent()->getParam('userinfo'); is also not available in constructor. So, forcing me to put it in each action.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to redirect user to login page if unauthenticated. For it i am writing
 if(!$auth->hasIdentity())
 {                       
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        return $controller->plugin('redirect')->toRoute('login');
 }
in onBootstrap function itself. But, it is showing "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Mvc\Application::redirect()"
Could you please also specify how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it. You can overload the ControllerConfig method in the Module class so you can instantiate the controllers however you like. Or you can write a controller plugin that will handle the authentication & return the identity.

## EDIT

Should have provided these links earlier, but didn't have much access from the phone ;).

To understand ControllerConfig take a look at [this blog post](http://www.zfdaily.com/2012/07/getting-dependencies-into-zf2-controllers/). There's an explanation about half way down of the getControllerConfig method in the Module class. This is a method the Module Manager looks for when instantiating the Module classes which allows you to customize the instantiation of a Controller in that Module. Once you return the Controller class, the Controller Manager then injects the rest of the Controller dependencies (plugins, etc.)

[Controller plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html) are small classes that get injected to every controller and which can be invoked from an action to do some common bit of code. When you use `$this->getServiceLocator()` in a controller action, you're using a plugin.

Comment: I am not familiar with these. Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: See my edit. You might also want to look at https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser and how they structure their Module class.